# error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, efk

I am getting this error from the fluentd pods and they keep restarting. I am running this on kuberentes v1.17.9-eks-4c6976.

Not sure of what the cause is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.4/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/http_server/compat/webrick_handler.rb:26: warning: The called method `build' is defined here
    2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2020-11-23 18:02:09.126315296 +0000 chunk="5b4c9fd811e8162eb94f03d8cec677e5" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch-master\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\", :path=>\"\"}): read timeout reached"
    2020-11-23 18:02:08.126340601 +0000 fluent.warn: {"retry_time":0,"next_retry_seconds":"2020-11-23 18:02:09.126315296 +0000","chunk":"5b4c9fd811e8162eb94f03d8cec677e5","error":"#<Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure: could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch-master\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\", :path=>\"\"}): read timeout reached>","message":"[elasticsearch] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2020-11-23 18:02:09.126315296 +0000 chunk=\"5b4c9fd811e8162eb94f03d8cec677e5\" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error=\"could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"elasticsearch-master\\\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\", :path=>\\\"\\\"}): read timeout reached\""}
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.2.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:1055:in `rescue in send_bulk'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.2.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:1017:in `send_bulk'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.2.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:842:in `block in write'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.2.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:841:in `each'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.2.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:841:in `write'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.4/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1136:in `try_flush'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.4/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1442:in `flush_thread_run'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.4/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:462:in `block (2 levels) in start'
      2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.4/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/thread.rb:78:in `block in thread_create'
    2020-11-23 18:02:08 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2020-11-23 18:02:09 475256825743319463889/8796093022208000000000 +0000 chunk="5b4c9fd80c4e40f1d7a4a799916ae12b" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch-master\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\", :path=>\"\"}): read timeout reached"
    2020-11-23 18:02:08.127449054 +0000 fluent.warn: {"retry_time":1,"next_retry_seconds":"2020-11-23 18:02:09 475256825743319463889/8796093022208000000000 +0000","chunk":"5b4c9fd80c4e40f1d7a4a799916ae12b","error":"#<Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure: could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch-master\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\", :path=>\"\"}): read timeout reached>","message":"[elasticsearch] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2020-11-23 18:02:09 475256825743319463889/8796093022208000000000 +0000 chunk=\"5b4c9fd80c4e40f1d7a4a799916ae12b\" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error=\"could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"elasticsearch-master\\\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\", :path=>\\\"\\\"}): read timeout reached\""}
```

Comment: You should also [open an issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/new/choose) for this on fluentd GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

The default `request_timeout` value for fluent-plugin-elasticsearch is 5s, which could often be too short when the fluentd has a large backlog to replay back to elasticsearch in large bulk messages.

So you may want to increase that `request_timeout` value for your elasticsearch output in your fluentd configuration to `15s` or even much higher - like say `60s`. It is important that you specify the time unit such as `s` also and not just the value of say `60`.

The documentation for the that setting can be seen here: https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#request_timeout

This could also be an indication that your elasticsearch node/cluster cannot ingest the data fast enough.